# Google Data Studio: How to calculate the number of days between two dates

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to calculate `Cost Per Lead` for a given date range from a static value `Spend`. The static value, `Spend`, is $2000 and is based on a 30 day window (1 month). The `Cost Per Lead` field is calculated by: `SPEND / NUMBER_OF_LEADS`. `NUMBER_OF_LEADS` automatically adjusts its value based on the date range selected by the user, but `SPEND` does not since it's a static value.

The questions is, how do I use Google Data Studio's date range selector in a calculation? Here is my formula using no sort of official functions or syntax – this is just to communicate what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
SPEND / [Number of days between start and end dates]
```

I've tried using Google Ads' date range in a formula, but cannot figure out how to calculate days between dates. Nothing seems to work.

```
DATE_DIFF( TODATE( MAX( date ), 'BASIC', '%d'), TODATE( MIN( date ), 'BASIC', '%d'))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows of data) 2) Expected output 3) Optionally (but preferably) an attempt at solving the issue so that there is a specific problem)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case. Without a **[Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart Configuration